# How to pass image/data to new view controller from iCarousel

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I have an iCarousel set up in one of my view controllers, and I would like to simply pass the same image that the user taps onto the next view controller. Here is what I have in my prepareForSegue on the Carousel VC:

```
 var padIndex = [UIImage]()

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {



   let nextVC = segue.destination as! BlackViewController

   let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

    nextVC.pad = self.images[indexPath.row]
}
```

Then in my secondVC I have:

```
var pad = UIImage()

@IBOutlet weak var padImage: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     padImage.image = pad
}
```

Seems like a simple thing, but I keep getting an error that says:

> Could not cast value of type 'SampleSequencer.ChooseViewController' (0x10213fe38) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x1025b8440).

Thanks a billion in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you that you've got an illegal cast. The error is here:

`let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath`

The `sender` argument of `prepare(for:sender:)` says that it can be `Any?`, but in reality, it's not terribly useful because you can't be sure what it's going to be. You have to get the `IndexPath` from the `iCarouselDelegate` (which is probably your own view controller, if it implements `iCarouselDelegate`), using the delegate's `carousel(_:,didSelectItemAtIndex:)` method.